# Email of new server working without changing nameserver

Tags: web-server, hosting, web-hosting, nameserver

I have a very weird situation. I bought a new hosting provider for my website. I was moving my website to the new hosting servers. So I uploaded all the public_html data, import database file, And create emails with the same name through Cpanel. Now I just needed to change the name server. But accidentally I sent an email from the new server cpanel->Webmail and guess what, **email sent successfully**, I didn't change any MX Records at the Domain Registrar Then how it is possible.
  It means anybody can buy a hosting plan for website x.com. And create an email address through Cpanel admin@x.com, And able to send an email with this email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess what? Anyone can use any email address they want, because email wasn't designed to provide strong identification. You can spoof sender address to be anything. Then, there may also be different sender in the `From:` header than the actual technical *envelope sender*.

The *mail exchanger*  `MX` records in DNS only affects to the mail received: it tells the other mail servers the servers responsible for accepting email messages on behalf of a recipient's domain. Then, secondary MX servers may deliver the message further to the server where the mailbox exists.

Fortunately, there are newer inventions to prevent unauthorized use of a domain in sender email addresses. The [*Sender Policy Framework* (SPF)](http://www.openspf.org/Introduction) introduces a type of `TXT` DNS record that tells the servers used for sending email from the domain. You can deny the rest completely with `-all`. But, SPF only protects the envelope sender:

> The **envelope sender address** (sometimes also called the *return-path*) is
>   used during the transport of the message from mail server to mail
>   server, e.g. to return the message to the sender in the case of a
>   delivery failure. It is usually not displayed to the user by mail
>   programs.
>
> The **header sender address** of an e-mail message is contained in the
>   `From` or `Sender` header and is what is displayed to the user by mail
>   programs. Generally, mail servers do not care about the header sender
>   address when delivering a message.

The moral of the story: never trust the email headers.

Comment: Thanks!, So Do I need to change MX records to get the email on new Server's Cpanel or just changing name servers is enough

Comment: Yes. And the old server will continue delivering mails locally even after that, as it believes it's still the server in charge. (This leads to a situation where you can only use completely external email for testing the new setup.)

Comment: I didn't need to change the MX records, I Just changed the Name Servers and after little down time. I automatically start getting the email on the new server.

Comment: You effectively changed the `MX` records by changing the name servers as they were configured differently there.

Comment: THEN Why did you say, I have to change MX records, I could have made a mess with MX records

Comment: Because this question was about email, and it's the `MX` records that actually makes the difference. The path you use for changing them (even when you have someone else to do that for you) makes no difference.